# Concatenating string to list iteratively

Tags: python, string, list, concatenation

So I'm trying to concatenate a string to a list, but for some reason it only works for the very last values:

```
labels_and_sents = []
for l in labels:
    for s in sents:
        sl = [l] + s
    
 labels_and_sents.append(sl)
```

Input:

```
labels = ['1','2','3']
sents = [['hi hello'], ['i was there'], ['this is a sent']]
```

Output:

```
[['3', 'this is a sent']]
```

What i need is:

```
[['1', 'hi hello'],['2', 'i was there'],['3', 'this is a sent']]
```

Comment: `output = list(zip(labels, sents))`

Comment: sl gets overwritten every iteration of the inner loop

Comment: Also, it doesn't really make sense to put a loop inside a loop since then you'd get 3 * 3 = 9 items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me this looks like task for `map`, I would do

```
labels = ['1','2','3']
sents = [['hi hello'], ['i was there'], ['this is a sent']]
output = list(map(lambda x,y:[x]+y,labels,sents))
print(output)
```

Output:

```
[['1', 'hi hello'], ['2', 'i was there'], ['3', 'this is a sent']]
```

Explanation: for every pair of corresponding elements from `labels` and `sents` I pack first one into `list` and then concatenate with latter. This solution assumes `len(labels)==len(sents)` does hold `True`.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to do it with **loop** then try following:

```
labels = ['1','2','3']
sents = [['hi hello'], ['i was there'], ['this is a sent']]
output = []

for i in range(len(labels)):
    output.append([ labels[i], sents[i][0] ])
print(output)
```

output:

```
[['1', 'hi hello'], ['2', 'i was there'], ['3', 'this is a sent']]
```